# Position HTML button dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, html, dynamic, button, positioning

I know this should be real simple, but I have googled this problem and I do not see the same available properties for my button.  What I have googled says I should be able to change an HTML button's location with the Location property.  However, this is not an option for me.  How do I change the button's location dynamically in C#?
Here is the relevant code in the ASPX.CS file:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int cnt = FindOccurence("DropDownListID");
    AppendRecords();
    pnlDisplayData.Visible = false;
    btnSubmit.Visible = false;
    resultLabel.Attributes.Add("style", "align=center"); 
    resultLabel.Visible = true;
}
```

I want to reposition btnSubmit.  In the ASPX file this button is defined as:

```
<asp:button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="Submit" width="150px" 
style="top:auto; left:auto"
OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:button>
```

Comment: location, like on the web page? also please put only the code that you're using to try accomplish what you want. Your question is just a little ambiguous, can you please try to clarify exacly what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your code I can see at the moment is that this line:

```
resultLabel.Attributes.Add("style", "align=center");
```

should read:

```
resultLabel.Attributes.Add("style", "align:center");
```

CSS properties are done like:

```
property:value;
```

**NOT**:

```
property=value;
```

Comment: Darko, I appreciate your suggestion.  I didn't fully explain what I wanted.  I wanted to reposition this button not only horizontally but also vertically.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

set style on control using [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style.aspx) collection, this will add properly style to existing styles on control defined inline:

```
resultLabel.Style.Add("align", "center");
btnSubmit.Style.Add("top", "auto");
btnSubmit.Style.Add("left", "auto");
```

setting exact absolute location of button:

```
btnSubmit.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
btnSubmit.Style.Add("top", "10");
btnSubmit.Style.Add("left", "10");
```